# Javascript div show hide onclick with image sprite

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, sprite

I am trying to work on writing a div swap with images using javascript. I have created two divs. One which is display block, and the second div which is display none. When the user clicks on the image, an onclick is supposed to hide the showing div and show the hidden div in it's place.

When the user clicks the same image location, the image shifts based on the xy value and the divs are supposed to swap out again. I cannot seem to get this to function correctly. I can get the click to swap out the divs when I don't set the display on either divs, but that leaves both divs showing stacked. I am almost there but cannot find what I am missing to only show one div at once. Is there a better way that I could be doing this? Please help?

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div style="border:1px dashed #CCC;background:#fff;padding:10px 0px;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div id="lifehacks" onclick="lhtrial();">
<div id="trialarea">
<p style="background: url('images/LH_Trial.png') 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p><span id="lhtext"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above To Opt-In To LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
</div>
<div id="trialarea2">
<p style="background: url('images/LH_Trial.png') 0 -75px;background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p><span id="lhtext"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above If You Want To Opt-Out Of LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
<script>

ele = document.getElementById("trialarea");
function lhtrial(){
if(ele.style.display == "block") {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    text.innerHTML = "show";
}
else {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work for you, although you are really better off attaching your events using [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of inline in the HTML.  You also identified the id `lhtext` twice in your HTML, which is not allowed.

```js
function lhtrial() { 
  ele = document.getElementById("trialarea");
  ele2 = document.getElementById("trialarea2");
  
  if (ele.style.display === "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
    ele2.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
    ele2.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```css
#lhimage1 {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/') 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  height: 75px;
}
#lhimage2 {
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/') 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  height: 75px;
}
#trialarea2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="lifehacks" onclick="lhtrial();">
  <div id="trialarea">
    <p id="lhimage1">&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span id="lhtext1"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above To Opt-In To LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
  </div>
  <div id="trialarea2">
    <p id="lhimage2">&nbsp;</p>
    <p><span id="lhtext2"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above If You Want To Opt-Out Of LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm Dave!! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function lhtrial(){
ele = document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display;
    if(ele == "block") {
   document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("trialarea2").style.display = 'block';
        text.innerHTML = "show";
        
}
else {
    document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("trialarea2").style.display = 'none';
   
    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div style="border:1px dashed #CCC;background:#fff;padding:10px 0px;">
<div style="text-align:center;">
<div id="lifehacks" onclick="lhtrial();">
<div id="trialarea" style="display:block;">
<p style="background: url('images/LH_Trial.png') 0 0;background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p><span id="lhtext"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above To Opt-In To LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
</div>
<div id="trialarea2"style="display:none;">
<p style="background: url('images/LH_Trial.png') 0 -75px;background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 75px;">&nbsp;</p>
<p><span id="lhtext"><span style="color:#999; font-size:12px;padding:20px 30px 0 30px;">(Click Above If You Want To Opt-Out Of LifeHacks)</span></span></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
    <button onclick="lhtrial()">button</button><!-- option 2-->
</div>
```

Test here [Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/4ja7Lt5h/2/)

I added this `<div id="trialarea" style="display:block;">` in html

and little change of js

```
    function lhtrial(){
ele = document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display;
    if(ele == "block") {
   document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display = 'none';
   document.getElementById("trialarea2").style.display = 'block';
        text.innerHTML = "show";

}
else {
    document.getElementById("trialarea").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("trialarea2").style.display = 'none';

    text.innerHTML = "hide";
}
}
```

And i added button but u can set other click event

```
 <button onclick="lhtrial()">button</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Aleksandar! Looks like everything worked with the exception of the image swap, but I think I needed to adjust my existing code to remove the main div's background.